# Calculate the Cyclomatic Complexity

Tags: complexity-theory

Calculate the CC (Cyclomatic Complexity) of the following code snippets.

I am not sure if I have drawn the Control Flow Graph correctly and furthermore if my calculation for the Cyclomatic Complexity is correct. And as for the formula `M = E - N + 2P`, the P is defined as "`P = number of nodes that have exit points`". Am I only counting the return here? How is it then with GCD2, if the method calls itself recursively does this also count as a return?

GCD1

```
public class GCD1 {
    public int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (a < b) {
            int t = a;
            a = b;
            b = t;
        }
        while (a % b != 0) {
            int r = a % b;
            a = b;
            b = r;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

GCD2

```
public class GCD2 {
    public int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (a < b)
            return gcd(b, a);
        else if (b == 0)
            return a;
        else
            return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

---

**Calculation**

M = E – N + 2P

where,

- E = the number of edges in the control flow graph
- N = the number of nodes in the control flow graph
- P = number of nodes that have exit points

*Control Flow Graph of above GCD1*

M = 7 - 6 + 2*1 = 3

[image]

*Control Flow Graph of above GCD2*

M = 8 - 7 + 2*1 = 3

[image]

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post, and we encourage you to try to formulate a question that is likely to be useful to others in the future -- e.g., a more general question about recursive functions in general would be better than asking us to check your solution to a specific exercise.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68242940/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/141983/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).